# Math functions does not work with operators in ElasticSearch scripts

Tags: elasticsearch

ES Version: `number: "7.0.1",`

The following query does not work. It returns `illegal_argument_exception` (Full Stack below).

```
   {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "SOME_QUERY"
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "Math.log(doc['SOME_FIELD'].value + 1)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I though it might be some problem with `doc['SOME_FIELD'].value` but apparently there's some syntax issue on `Math.*` functions when using an operator (`+` in this case):

- `"source": "Math.log(doc['SOME_FIELD'].value + 1)"` DOES NOT WORK
- `"source": "Math.log(1 + 1)"` DOES NOT WORK

while

- `"source": "doc['SOME_FIELD'].value"` WORKS
- `"source": "1 + 1"` WORKS
- `"source": "Math.log(1)"` WORKS

Full Stack Trace:

```
{
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "compile error",
            "script_stack": [
              "NaN",
              "^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "NaN",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
          {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "index",
            "node": "69HAL8sMS-afWoTxhMteKw",
            "reason": {
              "type": "query_shard_exception",
              "reason": "script_score: the script could not be loaded",
              "index_uuid": "ASy6y5zxRpqMFONSLED6IQ",
              "index": "index",
              "caused_by": {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "compile error",
                "script_stack": [
                  "NaN",
                  "^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "NaN",
                "lang": "painless",
                "caused_by": {
                  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                  "reason": "Variable [NaN] is not defined."
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "compile error",
          "script_stack": [
            "NaN",
            "^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "NaN",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Variable [NaN] is not defined."
          }
        }
      },
      "status": 400
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the value in doc['SOME_FIELD'].value is not numeric (NaN). Depending on your expected numeric type, you can (and should) evaluate the value in your script using regex  to determine if it parsed properly, like so:

```
def m = /^([0-9]+)$/.matcher(doc['SOME_FIELD'].value);
if (m.matches()) { 
  def number = Integer.parseInt(doc['SOME_FIELD'].value);
    if (number == SOMENUMBER) return true;
    else return false;
} else return false;
```

Remember that if you're running this, you'll want to have the script all on one line.

Also, you'll need to enable regex on your cluster if it's not already (in the elasticsearch yaml file).